How to print object properties in console.log nodejs
I have a body response like this
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2024-06-17T15:03:22.523Z",
    "depositAddress": "0x361aB827bAE8FB0893a3d532a7FcfdFb623E27af"
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2024-06-17T15:02:23.328Z",
    "depositAddress": "0xe6bb5d2aC7ed9bbbecCD25819CdC7928d73aF25A"
  }
]

And I want to display in console log only
0x361aB827bAE8FB0893a3d532a7FcfdFb623E27af
0xe6bb5d2aC7ed9bbbecCD25819CdC7928d73aF25A

I have tried writing
console.log(body[0].depositAddress);

But it only displays 1 address (0x361aB827bAE8FB0893a3d532a7FcfdFb623E27af).
How to write a script that should display 2 addresses? Thank You

Use a for loop?

Note that you're not working with JSON, you're working with a normal JS array of objects (JSON is just a string, that's not what you're working with, you're working with the result of that JSON string having been parsed and turned into normal JS data structures). Use array.map to map your objects to their depositAddress. See From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array

no, I just want to display the deposit address in the log console

Yes, so map your objects to their depositAddress, then console log the resulting array. And if you want a pure string, join that array using \n and console log that.

You would have to use a loop. If you want to make a one line command. Using the map function would be an easy way to print what you need.


body = [
  {
    "createdAt": "2024-06-17T15:03:22.523Z",
    "depositAddress": "0x361aB827bAE8FB0893a3d532a7FcfdFb623E27af",
    'name' : 'John'
  },
  {
    "createdAt": "2024-06-17T15:02:23.328Z",
    "depositAddress": "0xe6bb5d2aC7ed9bbbecCD25819CdC7928d73aF25A",
    'name' : 'Smith'
  }
]
const bodyArray = body.map(item => item.name);
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = bodyArray.toString();
 <div>
    <p id="text" style="color:black; 
        font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;">
    </p>
</div>



